# How $id helps in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, reference

I have made a mongodb document a reference of other document. But I think it is not working the way I want it to work like!

For example:

```
> db.ttt.insert({_id: "a", b:"b" })
> db.ttt.insert({_id: "b", b: {$id:"a" } })
> db.ttt.find()
{ "_id" : "a", "b" : "b" }
{ "_id" : "b", "b" : { "$id" : "a" } }
```

Since I am making my last insertion a referee to first so it should be an equivalent to:

```
{
   _id: "b", 
    b: {

         {_id: "a", b:"b" }

       } 
}
```

yet why this query fails?

```
> db.ttt.find({"b.b":"b"} )
```

I may have understood `$id`'s property wrong. But if it can't be done by referencing then what are the other choice do I have? and what is the advantage of referencing ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, embedding document inside a document is different then referencing a document. In your case, you are referring a document rather than embedding. So you are not suppose to treat it like embedded document. What you are doing is querying it as if you have embedded document which it is not.

Mongodb documentation is very clear about how referencing can be used and I think you must visit [the mongodb documentation for referencing](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/). But in short, once you have got the result from `db.ttt.find({ "_id" : "b"})` then your application should make another query to find the referenced document with the reference you got in the first query.

The important thing to remember is in case of embedded document you can run one query to get the result from embedded document whereas in referenced document you have to take help of second query.